# Are there any theories about computing speed propotional to object amount?

Tags: theory

If I want to calculate the movements of each moving objects driven by regular algorithm, then how can I measure required computing power? Is required computing power proportional to the quantity of the objects?

Comment: Your most useful measurements are going to be timing or profiling with actual instruments, not estimating by calculation.  There are many, many factors that will confound a performance calculation, including cache size, processor speed and compiler optimizations, to name just a few.

Comment: To Robert Harvey, actually I haven't enough knowledge to remind many other professional things which is intimately related with your comment, sorry, actually I'm a layman, it's my fault, I'm sorry, "There are many factors that will confound a performance calculation", so It's insufficient simply to calculate performance calculation, do I understand correctly? I'm so sorry, I've been let you down, but I really haven't enough knowledge. I'm so sorry. but thank you for proofread my question, and your lively comment. Thank you!

Comment: It might be worth understanding that commonly objects aren't copied around, the references to them are. Why move my house to where you can find it rather than just give you my home address?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the problem here is that you're a layman so much as we're left unsure what it is you're trying to do. You might have a very good question that is simply poorly expressed. We need questions that are useful to others and gather objective answers. It's OK to learn as we go here. For example, I have no idea what a "regular algorithm" is. But I think asking if the number of objects used in a design impacts its performance efficiency is an awesome question. Its unfortunately big enough to write a textbook about.  So we'd need a more focused question. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Dear.  CandiedOrange, Thank you and sorry for late reply, at this time I was foolish. I asked a question without any other background knowledge,  I acted with reckless bravado(although I was really curious about question  I asked).  Thank you very much for your sincere effort and kind consideration and words of encouragement regardless of my foolish act. have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [Big-O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

The core of an answer is already part of your question:

"... the movements of each moving objects driven by regular algorithm ...". So, if you have N objects, then the computation power needed is N times the computation power needed by the "algorithm".

Does the algorithm depend on other objects? Maybe because of collision detection or so? Then the computation power needed will typically increase more than linear with N.

If you don't have the years of experience so you can estimate the required computation power in advance, then implement your program and measure its performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I felt my question seems bombastic, but I didn't know how to describe what I was thinking. but you magically pointed out what i was thinking(even in case of collision.). thank you very much, I can feel your warm kindness in what you wrote.
thank you!